# If my GPU has 1x HDMI 2.1 port and my monitor (Full HD 100 Hz) has HDMI 1.4, what kind of HDMI cable should I get?

Tags: display, hdmi, connection, cable, compatibility

Asking because I genuinely am not sure and I don't want to waste money. If my GPU has 1x HDMI 2.1 port and my monitor (Full HD 100 Hz) has HDMI 1.4, what kind of HDMI cable should I get?

Comment: Any cable currently in the market will do.

Comment: The cable will likely last longer than anything else, so if you want to be future-proof, get HDMI 2.1, otherwise get a 1.4